# Formularios en Html

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

tengo un formulario el cual es muy extenso ya que son muchos campos a llenar y son obligatorios. Todos los muestro en una modal pero hay otros datos a llenar y estos son opcionales y no los quiero mostrar a menos que el usuario o administrador quiera verla. Quería saber si hay un método para eso, de darle a siguiente o marcar una casilla, presionar un botón, lo que sea, de forma que despliegue el resto del formulario a llenar y al final guarde los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocultar los formularios opcionales con css y mostrarlos con js cuando un checkbox esta marcado.

Ejemplo:

```
    <form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
  <br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
  <br>
  <label>Mostrar</label>
  <input type="checkbox" onchange='show(this)' />
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="otro" class="hide" style="display:none;">
  <input type="xd" placeholder="otro" class="hide" style="display:none;">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
<script>
  function show(bool) {
    var formset;
    if (bool.checked == true) formset = "block";
    else formset = "none";

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
    elements.forEach(function(name, index) {
    elements[index].style.display = formset;
    });


  }
</script>
```

Codigo editado

Comment: Gracias man, lo intentaré

Comment: Olvide que con la id solo se podría con un elemento, asi que edite el codigo, a cualquier input que le pongas class="hide", se ocultara y mostrara solo cuando el checbox este activo

Comment: osea, no hace falta css?

Comment: No, solo en las mismas etiquetas para ocultarlas